# Чем отличается использование require "path" и require("path")?

Tags: php

Имела место следующая ситуация: через PEAR была установлена библиотека, которая была доступна в любом скрипте проекта через

```
require "lib_name/lib_class.php";
```

Так вот для того чтобы подменить её на свою одноимённую (для дебага например), добавляли её в проект и "регулировали" использование библиотеки с сервера или из проекта соответственно использованием requare со скобками и без.

Соответственно делаем вывод (для относительных путей):

- `require ("file_name")` - ищет вначале `file_name` в папках из `include_path`, а   потом в папках проекта.
- `require "file_name"` - ищет вначале  в папках проекта, потом в папках из `include_path`.

Комментарий от админа:

> провели эксперимент - подтверждаю наличие указанного эффекта на версии `PHP 5.2.6-1+lenny10 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2`.

Очень хотелось бы от данного сообщества получить документальное подтверждение указанного эффекта :-)

От сборки к сборке php этот эффект не меняется. А натолкнула на мысль разной логики поиска подгружаемого файла документация к C++ (в ней это описано официально).

Comment: Подтверждаю. Отличия в этих двух способах использования require действительно есть. Не совсем прозрачные, но они есть! :)

Comment: Атака клонов. =)

Comment: Не уверен...

Comment: ну, тогда почему бы не ответить на вопрос? С вашим-то рейтингом пара плюсиков в карму за ответ(если он правильный) совсем не повредят.
Я понимаю, если бы, например, Sh4dow ломался, "давая другим подумать".

Comment: Для ответа на свой вопрос требуется 50 кармы...

Comment: К сожалению, кончился лимит комментариев к предыдущему ответу. Для Sh4dow: автор намекает категорически не на "эту фигню". Интересует принципиальное отличие использования обоих вариантов.

Comment: Я вовсе не клон sambady. Мы коллеги по работе и сидим в данный момент в 5 метрах друг от друга. Пока что правильно ответить на вопрос ни кто не смог)))

Comment: Тут просто дело в том, что здесь реальные вопросы обсуждаются, типа, можно кому-то помочь и самому чему-то научиться. Вы тут на моей памяти первые с таким сдвигом мышления в сторону оригинальности) Мне, если честно, влом искать инфу, чтобы ответить на "известный"(?) вопрос.

Если бы мне это было интересно, я бы и в универе остался. Удачи)

Comment: Подсказка: их отличие кроется в ядре PHP

Comment: Не, викторины тоже полезны(умеренно). Просто надо их как-то отдельно помечать: кинул весточку модерам, чтобы добавили тэг.  
Ес-но, викторины с нормальными ответами, на что я все еще тайно надеюсь в данном вопросе. Вдруг, какая-то полезная фишка, а не просто глюк конкретной сборки?

Comment: Реально нужна помощь. Сами потратили время на поиск официальной инфы, но успехом он не увенчался. А официальное подтверждение отличия необходимо. Вот и обратились к вам за помощью.

Comment: Тогда стоило, наверно, сделать подробное описание фичи(бага) с запросом подтверждения. Ну, просто как-то разделять викторины и вопросы, в конце концов. Я не против ни того ни другого, я против мешанины.

Comment: Короче говоря, вы, копаясь в исходниках какой-то сборки php, нашли ошибку и хотите, чтобы кто-то нашел ту же сборку и откопал там ту же ошибку? Я правильно понял?

Answer (score 3):

Только скобками. Функции require в PHP, насколько мне известно, нет. Скобки в данном случае просто избыточная группировка, точно так же, как у **echo** и у **return**.

**Добавлено.**

Думаю, учитывая "удалось выяснить опытным путём", автор намекает на эту фигню (или что-то типа):

```
// won't work, evaluated as include(('vars.php') == 'OK'), i.e. include('')
if (include('vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}

// works
if ((include 'vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}
```

Но она вообще слабо связана с сабжем. Скорее это относится к группировке в логических выражениях.

Comment: А вот и неправильно. Какие есть ещё идеи?

Comment: Это что, викторина? =/

Comment: порадовала всплывающая реклама "Профи ответят на твой вопрос". Ответа на этот вопрос в офф. документации нет. Отличия удалось выяснить опытним путём. Интересен ответ профи, подтверждённый ссылками на что-нибудь официальное

Comment: Ну и надо было сказать отличия(еще не факт, что они есть) и попросить ссылку на документацию. А так автор себе просто табличку на лоб повесил с известной надписью.

Comment: Цитирую вопрос "Чем отличается использование require "path" и require("path")?". Слово "отличается" в нём присутствует. Ссылку на документацию бы попросил, когда прочитал бы ответ.

Comment: Процитировать ответ? Ок, "только скобками". Это языковая конструкция и может использоваться со скобками и без.

Comment: Думаю, учитывая "удалось выяснить опытным путём" автор намекает на эту фигню(или что-то типа):


    // won't work, evaluated as include(('vars.php') == 'OK'), i.e. include('')
    if (include('vars.php') == 'OK') {
        echo 'OK';
    }
    
    // works
    if ((include 'vars.php') == 'OK') {
        echo 'OK';
    }  
    
Но она вообще слабо связана с сабжем. Скорее это относится к группировке в логических выражениях.

Answer (score 1):

> Because include() is a special
> language construct, parentheses are
> not needed around its argument. Take
> care when comparing return value.

_

> Так как include() - специальная
> языковая конструкция, скобки
> вокруг аргумента не нужны. Но будьте
> осторожны со сравнением возвращаемого значения.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php
Страница require() ссылается на include().

Comment: Вот я про это и написал в 7м комментарии к своему ответу. =)

Comment: Это, конечно, замечательно и имеет место. Но принципиальная разница в использовании этих 2-х вариантов есть и она не заключается в возвращаемом значении. Основное назначение этой конструкции - не проверка возвращаемого ей значения.

Answer (score 0):

Скобки обычно используются для передачи аргументов в функцию, возможно, require имеет не один аргумент, а т.к. обычно используют с одним, скобки опускают.

Comment: Ну, в задании указан только один параметр. Так что если бы там и был второй(в чем я как-то крайне сильно сомневаюсь) он бы не сыграл никакой роли.

Comment: knes +1 за коммент. Опять повторюсь, интересует отличие самой логики работы этой конструкции в обоих вариантах использования